# In Bash (Mac/Linux terminal shell), can the up and down arrow keys be made to function as they do in text editors?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bash, terminal

In text editors, if I press the up and down arrow keys, it moves the cursor between lines of text.

In Bash, if I’m typing a long command that spans multiple lines and I press the up and down arrow keys, it cycles through the command history.

I want the former behavior in Bash. Is this possible? If not, is there *any* way to move the cursor directly up or down in a multi-line command?

Comment: They move between lines... just that the line is very long.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  Bash uses [GNU Readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) to handle interactive line input.  There is no command in Readline that moves between display lines as you desire, nor is there a configuration variable comparable to the **line-move-visual** variable of GNU Emacs that causes next-line and previous-line to move by display lines.

Comment: Disappointing, but thanks! And I think the answers to another question would be useful to people with this same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657130/fastest-ways-to-move-the-cursor-on-a-terminal-command-line

Answer (score 5):

What I do is press CTRL + Left Arrow and it will leap to the first letter after the last space found. You can quickly get to where you need by doing this.

Comment: That's a non-standard key binding. The standard key binding for moving backwards by one word is Alt+b. See http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC5

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to navigate through words rather than characters, and <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> to go to the beginning and the end of the typed command.

Comment: Also, Ctrl+A to go to the beginning and Ctrl+E to go to the end

Comment: @ignis you should put that in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're looking for something like xiki. It's like a shell/text-editor.

Here's a video demo: http://youtu.be/bUR_eUVcABg

Comment: Xiki looks amazing! I want something like that that can run on windows...

Comment: @Max according to the projects github page, "We just patched el4r, so there's a chance Xiki might work in windows." You can check it out here: https://github.com/trogdoro/xiki

Comment: This is startlingly neat and nerdy, but really not what I was wanting to do. I just wanted to use Bash or some other common shell. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 2):

See also the `bash(1)` manpage under the heading `Commands for Moving` section for other navigation shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+A to go to the beginning and Ctrl+E to go to the end of the command.